# How to move current element to next position

Tags: python-2.7

intention is to infinitely cycle through a list, then just do this:
l=[1,2,3,4,5]

after first loop
l=[5,1,2,3,4]

after second loop
l=[4,5,1,2,3]

and so on,

without using double ended queue, itertool

use only simple list

Comment: This is one of the major use cases of `deque`s, why don't you want to use them?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it simply using this:

```
l = l[-1:] + l[0:-1]
```

So after 
first iteration it will be [5, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
after second [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]

Comment: solution will not be in place editing l[:] returns new list

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to modify the list inplace, you have to change its elements explicitly. This is done like this:

```
def inplace_rotate(l):
  l[:] = l[-1:] + l[0:-1]
```

This way, you do not reassign to the name `l`, but to the *elements* of the name `l`, which is visible to any code holding a reference to the initial `l` object.

You can also rotate multiple steps at the same time:

```
def inplace_rotate(l, count=1):
  if l and count:
    count %= len(l)
    l[:] = l[-count:] + l[0:-count]
```